# Calculating time of flight given index of refraction as a function of depth

Tags: speed-of-light, refraction, mathematics

Calculating light speed given a simple index of refraction is trivial, of course ($n = \frac{c}{v}$).

I'm not sure, however, how one would calculate the 'time of flight' for a light signal in a medium where the index of refraction is 'more complex'. Take ice, for example (which I'm working with here), whose refractive index varies as a function of depth. Suppose I'm given the coordinates of some light source, and some endpoint, in 3-dimensional space. How do I calculate 'time of flight' between the source and the endpoint?

I recall a method involving integrals, which seems intuitive to me, however I can't go off pure intuition, of course. Note that I'm ignoring birefringence, at least for now, as it is a very minor effect.

Comment: "ice ... refractive index varies as a function of depth" Can you give a reference for this?

Comment: If the refracrive index varies with depth, the light won't travel in a straight line.

Comment: The speed of light at some point depends only on the index at that point. It does not matter how the index varies with position.

Comment: Depths of 100 m, is this sea ice or some frozen lake? Was this measured on drill samples?

Comment: So this is about visible light and index variation over distances far greater than optical wavelengths. In such cases one can use ray optics and simply use a depth dependent phase speed c/n. One could take discrete intervals with constant n, apply Snell's law at the interface and then take the continuous limit.

Comment: Not clear. Are you really trying to find the speed of light at the endpoint? As nasu explains,  that is independent of the path. Or are you trying to find the time of flight between source and endpoint? That is where the integral is required.

Comment: @sammygerbil Yes, apologies, I'm referring to time of flight. I'll edit the question to make that more clear.

Comment: Then you will need to do something like the following : http://www.dartmouth.edu/~phys44/lectures/Chap_1.pdf. In general when the variation is not a simple function then you will have to use numerical methods. Which is actually easier. Since the variation is vertical this is really a a 2D problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Fermat's Principle, principle of least time.

Essentially you have the following:

The total time $T$ is calculated as follows:

$$T=\int{dt}$$

Using $v=\frac{ds}{dt}$ then:
$$T=\int{\frac{ds}{v}}$$

Using $v=\frac{c}{n}$ gives:

$$T=\int{\frac{n}{c}ds}$$

If your refractive index is a function of depth $y$ say $n=n(y)$ and $ds=dy$. You can then think of this equation as an Action. Then apply variation principles  $\delta T=0$ find the path your light beam takes.

In 2D you can use $ds^{2}=dx^{2}+dy^{2}$. This introduces a derivative into your integral which makes things more complicated.